# Expo print - landscape orientation on IOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I'm developing a React Native app with Expo, and I use `expo print` to make a PDF file from a HTML document. One of the PDFs that I make, needs to have the `landscape` orientation, so on Android I use `@page { size: landscape }` and it works fine, but on IOS, it doesn't. The same thing happens with margins, but it worked on IOS too with this:

```
const { uri } = await Print.printToFileAsync({ 
                html,
                margins: {
                    left: 20,
                    top: 20,
                    right: 20,
                    bottom: 20
                },
            });
```

So I was trying to find if there was a similar option for `orientation`, and there is, but that option is just for `Print.printAsync` and not for `Print.printToFileAsync`, that I use because it returns the URI of the created file, which the other one doesn't do. So is there anything that I can do to make it landscape and get the URI of the document?

Comment: Hi @Pedro Henrique, I'm having the same issue right know. Did you find any solution ? Thanks !

Comment: Hi @Yonnaled, I didn't find a solution for this using the `expo print`, so instead I created a Node.js backend to handle my PDF files.